# JSON parsing using Android native classes

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I want to parse a JSON file using native Android org.json.

The JSON is complex, and does not have a pre-defined structure. It can contain several levels of nesting for a key and just one value for another key. I can define any number of key value pairs with any type of structure.

I need to convert this to a dictionary. I cannot use any third party libraries like Jackson or Gson (for reasons I don't wish to discuss here). I do understand that it can be done very easily using the public APIs provided by these libraries.

If I want to do this on my own (using org.json perhaps), what is the best way to do it? Do I need to read every value, check if it is a JSONArray/JSONObject or a value and then perform recursion? Or can I just read the map that is in the JSONObject class using reflection and use it?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet to get you started:

```
Iterator<?> keys = jsonData.keys();
while( keys.hasNext() ){
     String key = (String)keys.next();
     String value =  jsonData.getString(key);
}
```

You will need to check if the data is an object or an array, here is how you do it:

```
if (item instanceof JSONArray)
{
    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) item;
}
else
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) item;
}
```

then use recursion to parse nested objects.

Good luck!